# What is the quickest way to open the pdf-manual for a given tex function or program?

Tags: documentation

Say I want to open the *PdfTeX manual* in PDF-format for reading on my screen. Or maybe get information about *nicefrac*. I don't want to `locate xxx` in the terminal ... What is the quickest way to open the pdf-manual for a given tex function or program?

Comment: `texdoc nicefrac`? If you know the name of the package, it will be a successful try to use `texdoc packagename` in about 99 % of all cases.

Comment: Oh,  and by the way.  The thing you want to know about nicefrac is that you want to use xfrac instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mostly use `texdoc <package name>`, but if this fail, my second option is go to `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/<package name>`, for example   https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac, and then go to the "Documentation" item.

Sometimes texdoc fails to find some related results even if the package exists (e.g. `texdoc outliner`), so this method can be safer than texdoc, mainly if you are unsure of exactly what you are looking for.

Sometimes there are more than one useful PDF (or plain text file) with the documentation for a package (for example, the package documentation and some examples of use for human beings, or several manual translations) but texdoc by default show only one. To list all search hits use `texdoc -l <package name>`. See also `man texdoc`.

On the other hand, https://www.ctan.org/pkg and https://www.ctan.org/topics/cloud are two useful pages if you are just "fishing" information, but you do not have a keyword to begin your search.

Comment: `texdoc` is not limited to PDFs!

Comment: @cfr I know, I know ...some times the doc is just plain text. I often use `texdoc xxx.sty` to investigate macro definitions, but the idea is that just "texdocing" could  pass unnoticed some information of you hard disk or CTAN.

Comment: But your answer implies that `texdoc` is unsafe because there might be a README rather than PDF. But it will open the README if so. Also, if I say `texdoc flowfram`, the first sentence of the PDF which opens is `This is the documented source code for the flowfram package. For a user manual, see ffuserguide.pdf (or do texdoc ffuserguide).` This includes a direct link to the user guide. So the user really does not need to guess in this case at all.... (But I think it would make a whole lot more sense to have the user guide open by default with a link to the other one.)

Comment: @cfr Upss, really was not a good example, I missed that sentence. `:)` What about  `texdoc outliner` ? This do not open the nonexistent PDF, nor `outliner.sty`, nor `outline_test.tex` that is in your hard disk. Then, you must search locally with `locate` or online with  CTAN, as the own `texdoc` suggest when it fails.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to use a web browser (as opposed to the command line), visit http://texdoc.net and type in the search box.

Answer (score 2):

If you have TexLive, you have texdoc:

Open a terminal and type:
`texdoc <search string>`

Where `<search string>` can be a package or class name or something else.

The default behaviour is something like google's "I'm feeling lucky", it opens the best fit in your default pdf viewer.
You can also list all hits with `texdoc -l <search string>`

Comment: In fact I wrote the answer before the comment and as the question mentioned terminal, I assumed program name and posix patter would be sufficient

Comment: Alt+F2 et al. are often faster than opening a terminal, if you have a system that has such.

Comment: @Raphael Why would you have to *open* a terminal? What a strange idea! ;) What is that combination meant to do, anyway?

Comment: @cfr I don't know, that's what MaxNoe said! To the point: on many GNU/Linux desktop environments, Alt+F2 opens a prompt you can type command names into. Similar to Start->Run... on (older?) Windows, I guess, but quicker to access and often more powerful (depends on the implementation).

Comment: Yeah,  something like dmenu,  for ecample

Comment: @Raphael I just can't imagine not already having a terminal open. There is some combination which gets me a command prompt. I don't think it is that one, though. I don't know what it is as I only ever do it by accident. Alt+Tab switches to a terminal. Alt+<number between 0 and 9> switches to another tab if the active one happens to be busy already. Or, in Kile, a terminal 'part' is right beneath the editing pane.